# Change Google Group language

Tags: google-groups

I created a Google Group and set the **Group's primary language** to *English (United States)*. My Google account preferences is set to French. When I invite a member to the group, he receives messages from Google in French language. If I change my account preference to English then the sent messages are sent in English language.

It is an inconsistent behavior. Normally if I set **Group's primary language** to *English (United States)* I expect that the sent messages are in English. The language of the sent messages should not be the one from my account preferences.

Am I doing something wrong? Someone can help?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you found the way that it's working. If you find this confusing or just don't like it, send your comments to Google.

1. Go to http://groups.google.com
2. [optional] Open your group
3. Click on the settings button > Help and Feedback
4. Click on Send Feedback
5. Fill-up and submit the feedback form.

Comment: I did it. Waiting for a reply from Google...
Thank you